# License of project files created with Blender

Tags: licensing

So I'm designing a game. I want to include not just the exported models but the original blender file as well. Am I able to do this without having permission or a licence?

Comment: Please try to give your questions meaningful titles in the future. The current one describes every single question on Blender Stack Exchange instead of describing this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do whatever you want with your files when you create them. Blender's license does not have any restrictions on the work you produce with it. In fact it has very few restrictions on what you can do with Blender itself.

You can read the license here: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html

The license also comes with Blender itself - in its installation folder you will find `GPL3-license.txt` file with all the text of it.

Comment: `"In fact it has very few restrictions on what you can do with Blender itself."` is not quite accurate, because the GPL is *very* restrictive about what you do with Blender-related code, even with add-on Python code you write 100% yourself.

Comment: @Keavon Well it's a copyleft license. You can do pretty much whatever you want with the code as long as you also license your derived code under the GPL3 license and distribute the source code with your program. Although I agree that a license, like for example MIT, could be consider more "free" because there are fewer requirements that have to be followed by the user of the source code.

Comment: @Keavon, I am talking about it from user's perspective in the context of the question. The user can even distribute Blender with their content if they wish following only a few requirements. You can even put Blender on a USB stick and sell it if you wish and find someone willing to pay for it. That is quite unrestricted the way I see it. Restricting your intention to put other restrictions on the code you write on top of it is another matter. I think this is outside of the context of the question because the question is more about freedom to use Blender for work.